# Updating HTML using an Excel file

Tags: html, excel

I'm creating a HTML showcase to access to an online store to show a series of main products with little data; something like an Instagram page. I already have it done and now I would like to make a massive data dump, since they are too simple, but different. It's name, main characteristic, price, reference, and some detail. All products have the same structure, for example:

```
            <div class="container">
                <span class="product_price">$39</span>
                <span class="product_name">Adidas Originals</span>    
                <p class="product_main">Men's running shirt</p>                                            

                <div class="product-options">
                <strong>SIZES</strong>
                <span>XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL</span>
                <strong>COLORS</strong>
                <div class="colors">
                    <div class="c-blue"><span></span></div>
                    <div class="c-red"><span></span></div>
                    <div class="c-white"><span></span></div>
                    <div class="c-green"><span></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How to make a massive data dump from an Excel file?

Sorry if this question already exists, I do not know the exact word of what this process is called to do a search on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have all product information in Excel. It also seems that you would prefer not to use VBA.

In that case, paste your html code into any cell, replace the "variable" section with a marker like %variablename%, for example

```
<span class="product_price">%price%</span>
```

Assuming your Cell is Sheet1!B1, or better, renamed to "rdata" then create a new sheet and reference to this cell

```
=Sheet1!$B$1
```

or

```
=rdata
```

now start changing the formula, substituting the variables with the values from your product sheet starting off with the first product, in this case row 3, price in column C, product name in B:

```
=substitute(rdata;"%price%";SheetProducts!C3)
```

add one more and again and again until you've done all variables

```
=substitute(substitute(rdata;"%price%";SheetProducts!C3); %productname%; SheetProducts!B3)
```

pull this formula down to as many rows as you have products, remember to save the excel file, then save this sheet as data type text, done.

Comment: Great, i'll try.

Comment: If this worked for you, please remember to set the Answer as accepted. Thanks! :-)